# Android: My imageview is rotated, but its touch area isn't

Tags: android, rotation, touch, imageview

I have a rectangular Imageview that responds to touch (it rotates by a specific number of degrees, using animation). The imageview has an ontouchlistener attached to it.

However, once it has rotated, it still responds to touch only at its original (pre-rotation) location. Even though I have setfillafter to true.

My theory is that the rotation is for display purposes only... is there a way to detect a touch on a rectangular imageview rotated at an angle - e.g. 45 degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When animation is applied to a view in android, only the pixels of the view are shifted while the hit area remains in the same position.

To actually move a view, you will need to add a animation listener to the view and manually change the view position on animation end.

Comment: Can a view be non-regular-rectangular: Like in my case at a jaunty 45 degree angle?

Comment: AFAIK you can not. As a Rect is used to specify the hit area. What you can do is sublass the view or imageview and overide the ontouch event and check if the touched region is inside the rotated rect and return accordingly.

Comment: As the rectangles are quite long, their hit areas will overlap, so what I will do is have more than one hit area per rectangle. More work, but ho hum...